# Can it be installed on a blank harddrive

Tags: software-installation

Can Ubuntu OS be installed on a blank(fresh) harddrive or does it have to be installed on a harddrive running windows?

Comment: I have no Windows on my entire system and have Ubuntu installed to my new SSD and to my new hard drive. You can use auto install options, but those only create / (root) and swap. With a newer larger drive / may be then very large and separate data partition(s) or /home may make more sense, but you have to use the Something Else install option. I normally partition in Advance with gparted. Is system UEFI or older BIOS? Makes some difference on partitioning.

Comment: You need only a computer with a hard drive in it and installation media to install Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't even need a hard drive.  You can do it with a USB thumb drive.

Answer (score 3):

It is not only possible to install Ubuntu on a blank disk, it is even slightly easier to do so than to install it on a disk where partitions already exist.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Yes.

---

While the Inside-Windows-installer called Wubi is possibly the first installation method a new user will discover, it does not mean that this is the only option. In fact, most other methods are easier and safer to use.

Ubuntu is in no way dependent on Windows. They are separate operating systems. Still, they (and most other OS'es) can coexist without many problems. From the nature of your question I take it that your understanding of what an operating system actually is and does is somewhat limited. You may want to [read up on this](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/computerbasics/2).

---

By default, Ubuntu is installed in partitions using the EXT4 file system. Windows uses the NTFS file system. Most UNIXoids, including Ubuntu, contain drivers for NTFS and can thus access the files on a Windows partition. Windows, on the other hand, does not ship with such drivers and can only access a small variety of file systems (NTFS, FAT).

You can install Ubuntu in an EXT4 partition on your hard drive, be there a Windows installed in a NTFS partition on the same drive or not. So multiple OS'es can go on one hard drive.

You can even do it the other way around: Install one OS on multiple drives. I'm not talking about RAIDs here. As an example, my core system is installed on a 256GiB SSD, but my user's home directory is stored on a much larger HDD, which gives me a good combination of the speed of a SSD and cheapness of HDDs. Another example could be a network setup where the system core is installed in a network share, and only host-dependent files are stored on local partitions.

---

So you see, the installation of Ubuntu is not dependent on the state of a hard drive, or multiple hard drives, before installation. You can install Ubuntu in any way you want, but I recommend you to stick to a simple one-hard-drive-setup, as you seem rather inexperienced with file system management to me.

---

If your real question is *how* to install Ubuntu, please read the [official guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) on how to do it.